# how can use php to parse json format?

Tags: php, json

how can use php to parse json format?

now I have this link : https://data.tycg.gov.tw/api/v1/rest/dataset/bed8a800-be39-4750-89a6-324b71f5d5fa

I want to parsing this json

```
{
  "identifier": "bed8a800-be39-4750-89a6-324b71f5d5fa",
  "categoryCode": [
    "e058256f-df7b-4a28-9b4e-6a70b73a0496"
  ],
  "title": "Taipei",
  "description": "Information。",
  "fieldDescription": "More information",
  "type": "Ori",
  "organization": "Travel",
  "organizationContactName": "Mr.James",
  "organizationContactPhone": "0912345678",
  "organizationContactEmail": "example@example.com",
  "accrualPeriodicity": "Now",
  "temporalCoverageFrom": "",
  "temporalCoverageTo": "",
  "modified": "2021-02-17T02:19:49.000537",
  "spatial": "Taipei",
  "language": "",
  "landingPage": "http://example.com",
  "numberOfData": "155",
  "distribution": [
    {
      "resourceID": "bd906b29-9006-40ed-8bd7-67597c2577fc",
      "resourceDescription": "",
      "format": "JSON",
      "resourceModified": "2021-02-17T02:19:49.000537",
      "downloadURL": "https://data.tycg.gov.tw/opendata/datalist/datasetMeta/download?id=bed8a800-be39-4750-89a6-324b71f5d5fa&rid=bd906b29-9006-40ed-8bd7-67597c2577fc",
      "characterSetCode": "UTF-8"
    }
  ]
}
```

but, when I use this code, it will get error.

```
$url="https://data.tycg.gov.tw/api/v1/rest/dataset/bed8a800-be39-4750-89a6-324b71f5d5fa";

$jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($url, true)),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) {
    if(is_array($val)) {
        echo "$key:\n";
    } else {
        echo "$key => $val\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I think the easiest way is just to use `json_decode` built in function. Just pass your JSON string to it and if you want it to be converted into associative array set the second parameter of the function to `true`.

Update:

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://data.tycg.gov.tw/api/v1/rest/dataset/bed8a800-be39-4750-89a6-324b71f5d5fa');
$jsonArray = json_decode($json, true);
print_r($jsonArray);
```

just tested it and got this result

```
array (
  'identifier' => 'bed8a800-be39-4750-89a6-324b71f5d5fa',
  'categoryCode' => 
  array (
    0 => 'e058256f-df7b-4a28-9b4e-6a70b73a0496',
  ),
  'title' => '桃園市景點資料(中)',
  'description' => '提供本市景點之觀光資訊，內容包含景點名稱、簡述、X座標、Y座標等資料。',
  'fieldDescription' => 'InfoId(序號)、TYWebsite(導覽網網址)、Name(名稱)、Toldescribe(簡述)、Add(地址)、Zipcode(郵遞區號)、Opentime(開放時間)、Px(X座標)、Py(Y座標)、Website(網站)、Parkinginfo(停車資訊)、Ticketinfo(費用資訊)、Remarks(旅遊叮嚀)、Tel(電話)、Fax(傳真)、Changetime(更新時間)',
  'type' => '原始資料',
  'organization' => '觀光旅遊局',
  'organizationContactName' => '曹先生',
  'organizationContactPhone' => '03-3322101#6209',
  'organizationContactEmail' => '10023909@mail.tycg.gov.tw',
  'accrualPeriodicity' => '即時',
  'temporalCoverageFrom' => '',
  'temporalCoverageTo' => '',
  'modified' => '2021-02-17T02:19:49.000537',
  'spatial' => '桃園市',
  'language' => '',
  'landingPage' => 'http://travel.tycg.gov.tw/zh-tw/Travel/AttractionList',
  'numberOfData' => '155',
  'distribution' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'resourceID' => 'bd906b29-9006-40ed-8bd7-67597c2577fc',
      'resourceDescription' => '',
      'format' => 'JSON',
      'resourceModified' => '2021-02-17T02:19:49.000537',
      'downloadURL' => 'https://data.tycg.gov.tw/opendata/datalist/datasetMeta/download?id=bed8a800-be39-4750-89a6-324b71f5d5fa&rid=bd906b29-9006-40ed-8bd7-67597c2577fc',
      'characterSetCode' => 'UTF-8',
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: it's will get 500 error

Comment: @ToRoTseng just updated updated the post, please have a look